# Is there any specific method to clean this kind of obj columns

Tags: python, pandas, split

`730 000 [500 000–970 000]

730 000 [530 000–1 000 000]

760 000 [550 000–1 100 000]`

I want remove the brackets as well as numbers inside the brackets in both the sheets preferably using python.

Comment: This a bad question please read more about how to ask a question on stack overflow  to have a better experience and get to the bottom of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex

```
import re

text = "730 000 [500 000-970 000]"
clean_text = re.sub(r"\[[^\[\]]*\]", "", text).strip() # replace bracket and stuff inside 
print(clean_text)
```